# ImportError: No module named threadedcommentsdjango_comments while use django-threadedcomments app

Tags: django, django-comments

I am trying to use django-threadedcomments app to allow comments in my website following the configurations mentioned `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-threadedcomments`. my installed apps are

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
# for comments
'threadedcomments'
'django_comments',
'django.contrib.sites', 
# installed apps
# APPS
'debug_toolbar',
#related to debug_toolbar
'haystack_panel',
'whoosh',
'haystack',
'taggit',
'question',
 ]
COMMENTS_APP = 'threadedcomments'
```

After adding the 'threadedcomments' app in the settings.py I am gettting the error when I run `python manage.py migrate` or `python manage.py runserver`

> ImportError: No module named threadedcommentsdjango_comments
>   Full Error Trace
>   [image]

however the code works fine without 'threadedcomments' and with 'django_comments'. 
I am using django 1.8.8 and posgres9.5. please help.

**note:**
I have already installed 'threadedcomments' app in my venv. 
[image]

Comment: stupid question - are you sure you have threadedcomments package installed in same env where you project lives?

Comment: @wolendranh yes I did, it looks stupid to me as well, may be because I am new, but I am not moving forward because of this issue.

Comment: Do you have imported that module somewhere? If yes - please show code.

Comment: i didn't mean that your question was stupid) I was talking about my own. Sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, In your settings you are missing ','(comma):

```
'threadedcomments'
'django_comments',
```

===>

```
'threadedcomments',
'django_comments',
```

If you were accurate you can find that in your own screen:

```
No module named threadedcommentsdjango_comments
```

there is no split between two packages.

Comment: thanks for pointing out @wolendranh, instead of syntax error it was throwing no model import error.